# pandas dataframe transforms with columns and specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

i am working with pandas with dataframe like bleow

```
area    date    m1  m2
IDC1    02/01/2017  400 80
IDC1    03/01/2017  400 70
IDC2    02/01/2017  410 204
IDC2    03/01/2017  400 214
```

i wnat to transform it to below, i have been seen the pd.melt,but still not working.

```
area    date    02/01/2017  03/01/2017
IDC1    m1       400         400
IDC1    m2        80          70
IDC2    m1       410         400
IDC2    m2       204         214
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['area', 'date'])
       .stack()
       .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
       .rename_axis(('area','date'))
       .rename_axis(None, 1)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
   area date  02/01/2017  03/01/2017
0  IDC1   m1         400         400
1  IDC1   m2          80          70
2  IDC2   m1         410         400
3  IDC2   m2         204         214
```